# Centos How to give permission to view folder ?

Tags: bash, ssh, permissions, centos, google-compute-engine

I push all the local files to Google Compute Engine using

```
gcloud compute copy-files
```

then login to VM using `gcloud compute --project` and view the uploaded file using ls command it's there .. No problem but when i login through Google Cloud ssh followed by the ssh window there. And i can't able to view the directory. This is simple queston but can't figure out.

```
dev_user_com@instance-1 home]$ ll -a
total 12
drwxr-xr-x.  4 root          root            35 Oct 29 06:22 .
dr-xr-xr-x. 17 root          root          4096 Sep 24 18:36 ..
drwx------.  4 dev_21six_com dev_21six_com 4096 Oct 29 07:17 dev_user_com
drwx------.  5 ri            ri            4096 Oct 29 10:15 ri
[dev_user_com@instance-1 home]$ cd ri/
-bash: cd: ri/: Permission denied
[dev_user_com@instance-1 home]$
```

Comment: Ok .. What i think is i just upload all files from my computer login. That's why it's not showing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The permissions are such that even `root` does not have write access.  Looks hard to fix, but `root` should have the powers to override write protection.  Just be careful to not change anything you're not supposed to.

Assuming you have `sudo` access, try this.

```
sudo chmod u+w .
sudo chown -R dev_user_com .
```

... assuming `dev_user_com` is your current login and the proper owner of these files.